# getting an Error "We couldn't find the record you're trying to access.......... for help." any idea?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, case, salesforce-classic

I am getting an error saying "We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Ask your administrator for help." when trying to view a case record from a profile, but i can see the same kind of another record from the same profile.
I also can see both the records from classic, but when i switch to lightning i am getting the error. any idea?

Comment: How are you getting the URL to the case instance? Do you have sharing rules defined?

Comment: the case is generated based on the conditions using builder. For the same kind of two case records i can view one and cannot view other. but i can see both in classic view. only problem is viewing them in lightning. Sharing rules are ok. is it something with spring 19 release?